# Sentence ordering with "doch"

Tags: grammar, word-order

> Die genaue Höhe der Zahlen ist umstritten, **doch gilt es als sicher**, dass Entführungen zu einer nicht unwichtigen Einnahmequelle von Terroristen geworden ist.

Is it also possible to say

> doch es gilt als sicher

or

> es gilt doch als sicher

?

If so, is there any difference between the versions?

Comment: You need to use *sind* instead of *ist* because the subject (*Entführungen*) of your subordinate clause is plural.

Comment: Here, a comma is correctly used before “doch” to separate two independent clauses. However, a semicolon is frequently used to connect such closely-related independent clauses. They could also have been separated by a full stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with "doch". doch (1) is a shortened form of jedoch and introduces a clause containing a contrary idea.

doch (2) is an adverb, a filling word, often called modality adverb as it marks a special attitude of the speaker towards what he says.

- Das weiß ich doch! marks some annoyance about being told things that are general knowledge for the speaker. This "doch" is placed after the verb.
- Ich bin doch nicht blöd! marks a statement as something self-evident.
- Das ist doch nicht zu glauben/unglaublich! marks a very strong emotion.

I haven't studied all the things "doch" can express but I am sure there are still some other "modalities".

There is even a "doch"(3). As an answer you can say: Ja/Nein/Doch - as Daniel has already pointed out in his post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the difference is that in the first example *doch* does not play a role, you can just leave it out. Instead in the 2nd example you gave you contradict the person you're talking to.

It makes a difference which word you emphasize. In the first: if you emphasize doch then it is like: yes, it is sure. if you don't emphasize any word explicitly then it is like without doch. In the second: if you emphasize gilt then it is just a statement. If you emphasize doch then it is the contradiction I mentioned above. Also that is used for changing a previous statement in which, in this case, you would have said it is not sure

Comment: Please feel free to [edit] your post in case you want to give some more information. Comments are not meant for that, they may disappear over time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first alternative is o.k., but to you use the second within the whole sentence you need to replace "doch" with "jedoch". Unfortunately I can't explain why - it's just my *sprachgefühl* as a German native speaker.

Semantically I don't see any difference among the three versions. It's just a matter of rhythm and maybe style.